# JPA Inject same EntityMgr in multiple components

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions

I will describe the issue short:
I have a SessionLayer on which I want to manage transactions
I have servicelayer which actually performs data access logic

Servicelayer has the entityMgr injected using JPA annotation:

```
@PersistenceContext private EntityManager eMgr;
```

Session Layer does not have the entityMgr injected, but by using following spring config, it does correctly manage the transactions:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
p:url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test" p:username="test" p:password="test" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" 
p:packagesToScan="com.model"> <!-- scans for entities (model) -->
<property name="persistenceProvider">
<bean class="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence" />
</property>
<property name="jpaProperties">
<props>
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
</props>
</property>
</bean>
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.session" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.session.util" />
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
<tx:attributes>
<tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
<tx:method name="*" />
</tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
<aop:pointcut id="testSessionOperation" expression="execution(* com.session.TestSession.*(..))" />          
<aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="testSessionOperation" />
</aop:config>
```

The above works fine ... **However what if i wanted a reference to the entitymgr in the SessionLayer.**
I have tried adding the `@PersistenceContext private EntityManager eMgr;` annotation. This injects an entityMgr, but not the same one as the servicelayer, so the changes on servicelayer are not committed when using that enitymgr to commit.
What would be the way to go if I wanted the entityMgr used by the servicelayer also on the session layer (without passing it back and forth offcourse).

I though about moving enitymgr to session and passing it service, this works but i don't want to pass it everywhere it is required, it should be injected.

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use additional class that contains common entity manager

```
@Component
public class EntityManagerProvider implements IEntityManagerProvider
{
   @PersistenceContext(unitName = "PU_NAME")
   private EntityManager entityManager;

   public EntityManager getEntityManager()
   {
      return entityManager;
   }
}
```

your business bean

```
@Service  
pucli class MyService  
{
   @Autowired
   private IEntityManagerProvider entityManagerProvider; 

   //.. entityManagerProvider.getEntityManager() -- accessss to entity manager  
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. It does seem like a soluton to the posed solution. 
However I'm still wondering ... :), is there no way to  inject the _same_ entitymanager in different components (during same sessoincall) using the @PersistenceContent annotation? Maybe it would work that way with the entityMgr/persistence context being managed by a (j2ee) container? Just wondering I don't seem to find a way to controle the "instantiation mode/behaviour" of the entityMgr and I think I might be missing something ...